# Jetpack Compose Desktop Layout components with different widths and heights

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-multiplatform, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I want to have my components layout in Jetpack Compose Multiplatform something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately ConstraintLayout is not available for compose Multiplatform ...

Any Ideas / Recommendations on how to achieve this best??

Comment: You are right, as far as I know there are no functions in the core Compose libraries that implement this. You could try doing it yourself using the `Layout` component. It's a bit of a steep learning curve, but very powerful once you learn how it works.